# I don't recieve the email which I sent after user registration

Tags: php, email, xampp

When a user creates an account he automaticcly gets an email with his username and password.

> ```
> $msg = "Hello '$username'\nLogin Data:\n\nUsername: '$username'\nPassword: '$password'\n\nThank you for registering here!";
> // Send mail
> $to = $email;
> $subject = "Welcome";
> $headers = "From:mail@gmail.com\r\n";
> mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
> header("refresh:5;url=../index.html");
> echo 'Registration successful. You\'ll be redirected in about 5 seconds. If not, click <a href="../index.html">here</a>.';
> ```

php.ini

```
 SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port = 25
 sendmail_from = email@gmail.com
 sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
 sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mail@gmail.com
auth_password=pass
force_sender=mail@gmail.com
```

Did I do something wrong ? :)

Comment: what's inside the `c:\xampp\mailoutput` file ?

Comment: To: mail@gmail.com
Subject: Welcome
From:mail@gmail.com

Hello 'user'
Login Data:

Username: 'user'
Password: 'pass'

Thank you for registering here!

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `sendmail_path` in `php.ini` setting it to use the `mailtodisk` utility. Which is working quite well. Remove this line `sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"` and you should be ok